# JavaScript call a php function?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Hello I have the following code that should execute a php file just before the user leaves the page.

```
              <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript">

              if(loged){
                    var Art = "<?php echo $id;?>";
                    var User = "<?php echo $email;?>";
                    var olikes = "<?php echo $Olikes;?>";
                    var odislikes = "<?php echo $Odislikes;?>";
                    var state = "<?php echo $state1; ?>";

                    window.onbeforeunload = function() {                       
                        $.get("dealLikes.php?article=Art&user=User>&state=1&likes=likes&dislikes=dislikes&Olikes=olikes&Odislikes=odislikes&prev=state");
                        console.log("hqhwegh");
                        return false;
                    };
             }else{}


              </script>
```

I want the JavaScript to run the deallikes.php file which just sends some data to a MySQL database. But the problem is that the deallikes.php file dosnt get run. What is the problem? Heres the deallikes.php file if you need it:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

 console.log("hello");
 </script>

<?php

session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include_once "mysql_connect.php";

    $articleid = '';
    $title = '';
    $userid = '';
    $State = '';
    $articleurl = '';
    $email = '';

    $log = null;

    if(isset($_SESSION["EMAIL"])){
     $log = $_SESSION["EMAIL"];
    }else{
     $log=null;
    }

    $log1 = null;
    if(isset($_SESSION["ID"])){
     $log1 = $_SESSION["ID"];
    }else{
     $log1=null;
    }

    if(isset($_GET['url'])){
        if(isset( $_GET['article']) && isset($_GET['user']) && isset( $_GET['state']) && isset($_GET['likes'])&& isset($_GET['dislikes']) && isset($_GET['Olikes'])&& isset($_GET['Odislikes'])){
            $articleid = $_GET['article'];
            $userid = $_GET['user'];
            $State = $_GET['state'];
            $likes = $_GET['likes'];
            $dislikes = $_GET['dislikes'];
            $olikes = $_GET['Olikes'];
            $odislikes = $_GET['Odislikes'];
            $Prev = $_GET['prev'];

        }
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION["EMAIL"])){
                            $fetchlast = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM likes WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM likes)");
                            $lastrow = mysql_fetch_row($fetchlast);
                            $lastid = $lastrow[0];
                                if($lastid == null || $lastid == '0'){
                                    $lastid = '1';
                                }

                            $i2 = 1;


                                $userLiked = false;
                                $userDisliked = false;
                                $userClearedLikes = false;
                                $userClearedDislikes = false;

                                if(($olikes-$likes) == -1){
                                    $userLiked = true;
                                }
                                if(($olikes-$likes) == 1){
                                    $userClearedLikes = true;
                                }
                                if(($olikes-$likes) == 0){

                                }
                                if(($odislikes-$dislikes) == -1){
                                    $userDisliked = true;
                                }
                                if(($odislikes-$dislikes) == 1){
                                    $userClearedDislikes = true;
                                }
                                if(($odislikes-$dislikes) == 0){

                                }
                             for ($i=1; $i <= $lastid+1; $i++) { 
                                $i2++;
                                 $current = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE id=$i");
                                             while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($current)) {
                                                         $id1 = $row[0];
                                                         $userid1 = $row[1];
                                                         $state1 = $row[2];
                                                         $articleid1 = $row[3];
                                                        if($userid == $userid1 && $articleid1 == $articleid){
                                                                    if($userLiked){
                                                                        $query8 = mysql_query("UPDATE `likes`  SET `state` = '1' WHERE `likes`.`id` = $id1;");
                                                                        $query5 = mysql_query("UPDATE `videos`  SET `likes` = `likes`+1 WHERE `videos`.`id` = $articleid;");
                                                                        if($Prev == 2){
                                                                            $query5 = mysql_query("UPDATE `videos`  SET `dislikes` = `dislikes`-1 WHERE `videos`.`id` = $articleid;");
                                                                        }
                                                                    } 
                                                                    if($userClearedLikes && $userDisliked == false){
                                                                        $query8 = mysql_query("UPDATE `likes`  SET `state` = '0' WHERE `likes`.`id` = $id1;");
                                                                        $query5 = mysql_query("UPDATE `videos`  SET `likes` = `likes`-1 WHERE `videos`.`id` = $articleid;");
                                                                    } 
                                                                    if($userDisliked){
                                                                        $query8 = mysql_query("UPDATE `likes`  SET `state` = '2' WHERE `likes`.`id` = $id1;");
                                                                        $query5 = mysql_query("UPDATE `videos`  SET `dislikes` = `dislikes`+1 WHERE `videos`.`id` = $articleid;");
                                                                        if($Prev == 1){
                                                                            $query5 = mysql_query("UPDATE `videos`  SET `likes` = `likes`-1 WHERE `videos`.`id` = $articleid;");    
                                                                        }
                                                                    }   
                                                                    if($userClearedDislikes  && $userLiked == false){
                                                                        $query8 = mysql_query("UPDATE `likes`  SET `state` = '0' WHERE `likes`.`id` = $id1;");
                                                                        $query5 = mysql_query("UPDATE `videos`  SET `dislikes` = `dislikes`+1 WHERE `videos`.`id` = $articleid;");
                                                                    } 
                                                        }
                                            }
                                }
                                /*
                                $query8 = mysql_query("UPDATE `likes`  SET `state` = '$fstate' WHERE `likes`.`id` = $id1;");
                                $query5 = mysql_query("UPDATE `videos`  SET `likes` = `likes`+1 WHERE `videos`.`id` = $articleid;");
                                $query9 = mysql_query("UPDATE `videos`  SET `dislikes` = `dislikes`-1 WHERE `videos`.`id` = $articleid;");
                                */
                     if($i2 > $lastid+1){
                        if($userLiked){
                        $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO likes (`id`, `userid`, `state`, `articleid`) VALUES ('', '$userid', '1', '$articleid');");
                        $query1 = mysql_query("UPDATE `videos`  SET `likes` = `likes`+1 WHERE `videos`.`id` = '$articleid'");
                        $i = $lastid+2;
                        }else if($userDisliked){
                        $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO likes (`id`, `userid`, `state`, `articleid`) VALUES ('', '$userid', '2', '$articleid');");
                        $query1 = mysql_query("UPDATE `videos`  SET `dislikes` = `dislikes`+1 WHERE `videos`.`id` = '$articleid'");
                        $i = $lastid+2;
                        }
                     }


    }else{}



?>
```

Comment: loged is true or false?

Comment: Came here to ask the same q. What is the value of loged?

Comment: its true if the user is loged in so for this it is true

Comment: any errors in the dev console or in the php error log?

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** `mysql_*` functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: where do i see the php error log

Comment: Please try using browser debugger to step through the code and see if that get is being called. Also if you have any exceptions in your console

Comment: I am now fairly sure the $.get part is not working, whats wrong with it